# Value not displayed in circle section

Tags: java, paint, graphics2d

I want to draw a circle, then divide it into 24 equal sections, with different colors. Then add the corresponding number to each section (1 to 24)

I'm facing an issue having all the numbers displayed, where only 13 until 24 are visible as seen here
[image: 13 to 24 numbers]

However if I change my condition to traverse only 12 numbers, they will be displayed but the section won't be filled as seen here

[image: 1 to 12 without section color]

Here's my code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class DividedCircleWithColorsAndNumbersExample extends JFrame {
    private final Color[] segmentColors = {
            Color.RED, Color.GREEN, Color.BLUE, Color.YELLOW, Color.ORANGE, Color.CYAN,
            Color.MAGENTA, Color.PINK, Color.LIGHT_GRAY, Color.DARK_GRAY, Color.GRAY,
            Color.BLACK, Color.CYAN, Color.RED, Color.GREEN, Color.BLUE, Color.YELLOW,
            Color.ORANGE, Color.CYAN, Color.MAGENTA, Color.PINK, Color.LIGHT_GRAY,
            Color.DARK_GRAY, Color.GRAY, Color.BLACK
    };

    public DividedCircleWithColorsAndNumbersExample() {
        setTitle("Divided Circle with Colors and Numbers Example");
        setSize(400, 400);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        int centerX = getWidth() / 2;
        int centerY = getHeight() / 2;
        int radius = 150;

        int x = centerX - radius;
        int y = centerY - radius;
        int diameter = 2 * radius;

        double angle = 2 * Math.PI / 24; // Angle between each segment

        for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
            g2d.setColor(segmentColors[i]);
            int startAngle = (int) Math.toDegrees(i * angle);
            int arcAngle = (int) Math.toDegrees(angle);
            g2d.fillArc(x, y, diameter, diameter, startAngle, arcAngle);

            g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            Font font = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 16);
            g2d.setFont(font);

            int labelRadius = radius - 30;
            int labelX = (int) (centerX + labelRadius * Math.cos(i * angle + angle / 2));
            int labelY = (int) (centerY + labelRadius * Math.sin(i * angle + angle / 2));
            drawCenteredString(g2d, String.valueOf(i + 1), labelX, labelY);
        }
    }

    private void drawCenteredString(Graphics2D g2d, String text, int x, int y) {
        FontMetrics fm = g2d.getFontMetrics();
        int textWidth = fm.stringWidth(text);
        int textHeight = fm.getHeight();
        g2d.drawString(text, x - textWidth / 2, y + textHeight / 4);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            new DividedCircleWithColorsAndNumbersExample();
        });
    }
}
```

I can't figure out the problem

**Update: If I split the section filling and setting the text into 2 separate loops it works**
[image: Split]

The code will be

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class DividedCircleWithColorsAndNumbersExample extends JFrame {

    private final Color[] segmentColors = {
        Color.RED, Color.GREEN, Color.BLUE, Color.YELLOW, Color.ORANGE, Color.CYAN,
        Color.MAGENTA, Color.PINK, Color.LIGHT_GRAY, Color.DARK_GRAY, Color.GRAY,
        Color.BLACK, Color.WHITE, Color.RED, Color.GREEN, Color.BLUE, Color.YELLOW,
        Color.ORANGE, Color.CYAN, Color.MAGENTA, Color.PINK, Color.LIGHT_GRAY,
        Color.DARK_GRAY, Color.GRAY, Color.BLACK
    };

    public DividedCircleWithColorsAndNumbersExample() {
        setTitle("Divided Circle with Colors and Numbers Example");
        setSize(400, 400);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
//        setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        int centerX = getWidth() / 2;
        int centerY = getHeight() / 2;
        int radius = 150;

        int x = centerX - radius;
        int y = centerY - radius;
        int diameter = 2 * radius;

        double angle = 2 * Math.PI / 24; // Angle between each segment

        for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
            g2d.setColor(segmentColors[i]);
            int startAngle = (int) Math.toDegrees(i * angle);
            int arcAngle = (int) Math.toDegrees(angle);
            g2d.fillArc(x, y, diameter, diameter, startAngle, arcAngle);

        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++) {

            g2d.setColor(Color.black);
            Font font = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 16);
            g2d.setFont(font);

            int labelRadius = radius - 30;
            int labelX = (int) (centerX + labelRadius * Math.cos(i * angle + angle / 2));
            int labelY = (int) (centerY + labelRadius * Math.sin(i * angle + angle / 2));
            drawCenteredString(g2d, String.valueOf(i + 1), labelX, labelY);
        }
    }

    private void drawCenteredString(Graphics2D g2d, String text, int x, int y) {
        FontMetrics fm = g2d.getFontMetrics();
        int textWidth = fm.stringWidth(text);
        int textHeight = fm.getHeight();
        g2d.drawString(text, x - textWidth / 2, y + textHeight / 4);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            new DividedCircleWithColorsAndNumbersExample();
        });
    }
}
```

It seems that the section filling is overlapping the numbering

**Update by taking into consideration the comment here's the updated code**

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class DividedCircleWithColorsAndNumbersExample extends JFrame {
    private final Color[] segmentColors = {
            Color.RED, Color.GREEN, Color.BLUE, Color.YELLOW, Color.ORANGE, Color.CYAN,
            Color.MAGENTA, Color.PINK, Color.LIGHT_GRAY, Color.DARK_GRAY, Color.GRAY,
            Color.BLACK, Color.WHITE, Color.RED, Color.GREEN, Color.BLUE, Color.YELLOW,
            Color.ORANGE, Color.CYAN, Color.MAGENTA, Color.PINK, Color.LIGHT_GRAY,
            Color.DARK_GRAY, Color.GRAY, Color.BLACK
    };

    public DividedCircleWithColorsAndNumbersExample() {
        setTitle("Divided Circle with Colors and Numbers Example");
        setSize(400, 400);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
//        setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        int centerX = getWidth() / 2;
        int centerY = getHeight() / 2;
        int radius = 150;

        int x = centerX - radius;
        int y = centerY - radius;
        int diameter = 2 * radius;

        double angle = 2 * Math.PI / 24; // Angle between each segment

        for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
            g2d.setColor(segmentColors[i]);
            int startAngle = (int) Math.toDegrees(i * angle);
            int arcAngle = (int) Math.toDegrees(angle);
            g2d.fillArc(x, y, diameter, diameter, startAngle, arcAngle);

            g2d.setColor(Color.black);
            Font font = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 16);
            g2d.setFont(font);

            int labelRadius = radius - 30;
            int labelX = (int) (centerX + labelRadius * Math.cos(i * angle + angle / 2));
            int labelY = (int) (centerY + labelRadius * Math.sin(i * angle + angle / 2) * (-1));
            drawCenteredString(g2d, String.valueOf(i + 1), labelX, labelY);
        }
    }

    private void drawCenteredString(Graphics2D g2d, String text, int x, int y) {
        FontMetrics fm = g2d.getFontMetrics();
        int textWidth = fm.stringWidth(text);
        int textHeight = fm.getHeight();
        g2d.drawString(text, x - textWidth / 2, y + textHeight / 4);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            new DividedCircleWithColorsAndNumbersExample();
        });
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I fixed it but by separating the loops. One loop for filling the sections, and another loop for entering the text. I appreciate if someone can help me fix it using 1 loop.

Added the split loop to the code above

Comment: basically code was drawing colors in one direction and number in the other, so arcs after half are overdrawing the numbers (basically the iteration that would come next on second image) - if you use `-sin` for label (`... centerY - labelRadius * Math.sin( ...`) it should work

Comment: from [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Graphics.html#fillArc(int,int,int,int,int,int)) of `fillArc`: "Angles are interpreted such that 0 degrees is at the 3 o'clock position. A positive value indicates a **counter-clockwise** rotation..." (emphasis mine) but positive y is *downwards*